# java launch no console window in Windows 7

Tags: java, javaw

I've already seen this questions, but have no positive result:

1) [Is there a way to the hide win32 launch console from a Java program (if possible without JNI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264687/is-there-a-way-to-the-hide-win32-launch-console-from-a-java-program-if-possible)
2) [Start a java program without the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710839/start-a-java-program-without-the-console)

I've something like that:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_71\bin\javaw" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp ".;manyjarshere.jar" main.Main

And console appears, but I can close it manually, but I want it hidden by start.
If I place "start" before "C:..." then it shows "not found "-Dfile..."

Answer (score 0):

`start javaw [args]` should do the trick **IF** java `/bin` folder is added to the system's `PATH` environment variable

Comment: It doesn't help. Application doesn't start even